# Python jxmlease issue

Tags: python, linux, redhat

I have tested this on CentOs 7 and Redhat 7.4

by default python 2.7.5 is present

I installed PIP install with the EPEL Repo

```
pip install jxmlease
```

jxmlease 1.0.1 is installed

But when I want to use jxmlease module in a python script I get the following error

```
import jxmlease
```

**Importerror> No module named jxmlease**

Comment: Could you please provide the output from `pip freeze`?

Comment: backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
configobj==4.7.2
decorator==3.4.0
iniparse==0.4
jxmlease==1.0.1
perf==0.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.22.0
pygpgme==0.3
pyliblzma==0.5.3
python-linux-procfs==0.4.9
pyudev==0.15
pyxattr==0.5.1
schedutils==0.4
slip==0.4.0
slip.dbus==0.4.0
urlgrabber==3.10
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.4
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with installing python 2.7.14